# Does $\ell^3$ norm preserving linear transforms exist?

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Does there exist a linear transform from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ that preserves the $\ell^3$ norm?

It is immediately obvious that combinations of permutations and change of sign of individual coordinates satisfy it.

I am wondering if there are more linear transforms that preserves the norm.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given a linear transformation $\,(x,y)\to (X,Y) := (a x+b y,c x+d y)\,$
then the condition for preserving $\,|x|^3+|y|^3\,$ splits
into cases depending on the signs of $\,x\,$ and $\,y.\,$
and also $\,X\,$ and $\,Y.$
For the case $\,x>0,\,y>0,\,X>0,\,Y>0$ we must have
$$ a^3+c^3=b^3+d^3=1, \quad a\,b^2+c\,d^2=a^2 b+c^2 d=0.$$
The two **real** solutions of this system of equations is
$\,(X,Y) = (x,y)\,$ and $\,(X,Y) = (y,x).$

The other cases are similar and allows to negate $\,X\,$
or $\,Y.$

Comment: What should be preserved is $|x|^3 + |y|^3$ (Hence why op said sign flips)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for that helpful comment!